# Building pjSip 2.5 - unable to undefined reference to 'pj_jni_jvm'

Tags: android-ndk, pjsip

Trying to build pjSIP from sources for Android, using following guide - https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android

1. Checkout sources of pjsip (2.5)
2. export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/home/dev/android/android-ndk-r9b
3. export TARGET_ABI=armeabi
4. export APP_PLATFORM=android-13
5. `./configure-android --use-ndk-cflags --disable-video --disable-l16-codec --disable-gsm-codec --disable-g722-codec --disable-g7221-codec --disable-ssl --disable-ilbc-codec --disable-tls`
6. configuration is completed successfully.
7. make dep && make clean && make

And I got following error - >

```
../src/pj/guid_android.c:43: error: undefined reference to 'pj_jni_jvm'
../src/pj/guid_android.c:117: error: undefined reference to 'pj_jni_jvm'
```

The command invoked by linked which leads to this error

```
/home/dev/android/android-ndk-r9b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -o ../bin/pjlib-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi \
             output/pjlib-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/main.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/activesock.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/atomic.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/echo_clt.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/errno.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/exception.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/fifobuf.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/file.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/hash_test.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/ioq_perf.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/ioq_udp.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/ioq_unreg.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/ioq_tcp.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/list.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/mutex.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/os.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/pool.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/pool_perf.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/rand.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/rbtree.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/select.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/sleep.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/sock.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/sock_perf.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/ssl_sock.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/string.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/test.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/thread.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/timer.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/timestamp.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/udp_echo_srv_sync.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/udp_echo_srv_ioqueue.o  output/pjlib-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/util.o -lpj-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi  -nostdlib -L/home/dev/android/android-ndk-r9b/platforms/android-13/arch-arm/usr/lib -L/home/dev/android/android-ndk-r9b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/armeabi/ -lm /home/dev/android/android-ndk-r9b/platforms/android-13/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o -lgnustl_static  -lc -lgcc -ldl -lOpenSLES -llog   -L/home/dev/android/pjproject-2.5/pjlib/lib -L/home/dev/android/pjproject-2.5/pjlib-util/lib -L/home/dev/android/pjproject-2.5/pjnath/lib -L/home/dev/android/pjproject-2.5/pjmedia/lib -L/home/dev/android/pjproject-2.5/pjsip/lib -L/home/dev/android/pjproject-2.5/third_party/lib           -nostdlib -L/home/dev/android/android-ndk-r9b/platforms/android-13/arch-arm/usr/lib -L/home/dev/android/android-ndk-r9b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/armeabi/
```

Code of guid_androind.c

```
#include <pj/guid.h>
#include <pj/log.h>
#include <pj/string.h>

#include <jni.h>

extern JavaVM *pj_jni_jvm;

static pj_bool_t attach_jvm(JNIEnv **jni_env)
{
    if ((*pj_jni_jvm)->GetEnv(pj_jni_jvm, (void **)jni_env,
                               JNI_VERSION_1_4) < 0)
    {
        if ((*pj_jni_jvm)->AttachCurrentThread(pj_jni_jvm, jni_env, NULL) < 0)
        {
            jni_env = NULL;
            return PJ_FALSE;
        }
        return PJ_TRUE;
    }

    return PJ_FALSE;
}

#define detach_jvm(attached) \
    if (attached) \
        (*pj_jni_jvm)->DetachCurrentThread(pj_jni_jvm);
```

Struggling with this error for whole day, any clue is highly appreciated. Meanwhile I'm able to build version 2.3 without any errors, but not 2.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you missed a step.
https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android#BuildPreparation

Set your config_site.h to the following:

```
/* Activate Android specific settings in the 'config_site_sample.h' */
#define PJ_CONFIG_ANDROID 1
#include <pj/config_site_sample.h>
```

Comment: ```/* Activate Android specific settings in the 'config_site_sample.h' */
#define PJ_CONFIG_ANDROID 1
#include <pj/config_site_sample.h>```

This does not help. Interesting here: If I build for armeabi-v7a, everything goes well. Build fails, however, for x86.